# ReactJS PowerBI Developer Samples throwing error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I'm testing powerbi with react using MS's https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/ repo. However I'm getting an error from:

https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/blob/master/React-TS/Embed%20for%20your%20organization/UserOwnsData/src/App.tsx#L108

```
reportContainer = reportRef["current"];
```

The error is:

```
TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"current"' can't be used to index type '((instance: HTMLDivElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLDivElement>'.   Property 'current' does not exist on type '((instance: HTMLDivElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLDivElement>'.
```

I haven't seen this syntax before and I'm not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

It is working fine in my system, please provide additional information.

This is how my Package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "powerbi-embedded-sample",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.9.23",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.5",
    "msal": "^1.4.1",
    "powerbi-client": "^2.16.5",
    "react": "^16.13.0",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.4",
    "typescript": "^3.7.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "lint": "eslint **/*.{ts,tsx} --quiet --fix"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.26.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.19.0",
    "object-path": ">=0.11.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to give a solution here

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31374178)